# Yarn build doesn't respect route rules in nuxt3

Tags: javascript, yarnpkg, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

I have a nuxt config defined as follows with prerender route and rules ssr: false route rules. However, when I use nuxt build, almost no routes are prerendered.

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    components: true,
    routeRules: {
        '/**': { prerender: true },
        '/blog/**': { prerender: true },
        '/blogs/**': { ssr: false },
        '/dashboard/**': { ssr: false },
        '/account/**': { ssr: false }
    },
    modules: ['@nuxtjs/tailwindcss', '@pinia/nuxt', '@vueuse/nuxt', '@pinia-plugin-persistedstate/nuxt', '@nuxt/content'],
    build: {
        transpile: ['@heroicons/vue', 'date-fns', 'chartjs-adapter-date-fns', 'chart.js']
    },
    content: {
        experimental: {
          clientDb: true
        },
        markdown: {
          toc: { depth: 3, searchDepth: 3 }
        }
    },
    nitro: {
        prerender: {
          routes: ['/sitemap.xml']
        }
      },
    tailwindcss: {
        exposeConfig: true
      }

})
```

For my blog and blogs I use nuxt content with the following package.json:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "dev": "nuxt dev",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "preview": "nuxt preview"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxt/content": "2.6.0",
    "@nuxtjs/tailwindcss": "^6.4.0",
    "@tailwindcss/aspect-ratio": "^0.4.0",
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.2",
    "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.5.9",
    "@vueuse/nuxt": "^9.12.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.7",
    "consola": "^3.2.2",
    "nuxt": "^3.6.1",
    "postcss": "^8.4.21",
    "sitemap": "^7.1.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@headlessui/vue": "^1.7.10",
    "@heroicons/vue": "^2.0.15",
    "@pinia-plugin-persistedstate/nuxt": "^1.0.0",
    "@pinia/nuxt": "^0.4.1",
    "@tailwindcss/line-clamp": "^0.4.0",
    "@vueuse/core": "^9.12.0",
    "chart.js": "^3.9.1",
    "chartjs-adapter-date-fns": "^3.0.0",
    "date-fns": "^2.28.0",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.5",
    "eslint": "^8.44.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "litepie-datepicker": "^1.0.14",
    "pinia": "^2.0.30",
    "pinia-plugin-persistedstate": "^3.0.2",
    "serve": "^14.2.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.6",
    "vue": "^3.2.47",
    "vue-chartjs": "^4.1.2",
    "vue-gtag": "^2.0.1"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "litepie-datepicker": {
      "tailwindcss": "^3.1.8"
    }
  }
```

}

However, my nuxt build only generates 2 route with prerendering:

```
ℹ Prerendering 2 routes                                                                                                                                                                                                nitro 13:51:28
  ├─ /api/_content/cache.1689249021101.json (982ms)                                                                                                                                                                     nitro 13:51:29
  ├─ /sitemap.xml (33ms)
```

I can't use yarn generate, since that doesn't work with hybrid rendering. Source:
https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/concepts/rendering

How can I make yarn build respect the route rules?